# Passing a block device to Qemu

Tags: qemu, block-device

Passing a block device to Qemu 3.0.1 like this works but yields a deprecation warning:

```
-blockdev file,node-name=f1,filename=/dev/loop0 \
-blockdev raw,node-name=q1,file=f1 \
-device virtio-blk,drive=q1
```

The warning:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -blockdev file,node-name=f1,filename=/dev/loop0: 
  warning: Opening a block device as a file using the 'file' driver
    is deprecated
```

Fair enough, but how do I pass a block device to qemu without using the 'file' driver?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should [use `host_device` instead](https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=commit;h=230ff73904e72dde2d7718c2da407786a1c72e57), which is admittedly difficult since it’s not documented.

In your case, the non-deprecated options are

```
-blockdev node-name=q1,driver=raw,file.driver=host_device,file.filename=/dev/loop0 \
-device virtio-blk,drive=q1
```

Comment: Great find! This works. Btw, meanwhile I've worked around this with `-drive file=/dev/loop0,if=none,format=raw,aio=native,cache=none,id=q1 -device virtio-blk,drive=q1` although I remember a qemu Fosdem 2018 talk where the speaker categorized `-drive` as legacy option. With `-drive` the warning also goes away, so perhaps qemu translates it into a `driver=host_device` setup. Or it does something completely different ... :)

Comment: never heard `-drive` labelled as legacy option before. manpage mentions no such thing either (it does for other legacy options)

Comment: @frostschutz [Thomas Huth. Finding your way through the QEMU paramter jungle. Fosdem 2018](https://fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/vai_qemu_jungle/attachments/slides/2539/export/events/attachments/vai_qemu_jungle/slides/2539/qemu_cli_jungle.pdf) especially pages 10, 20 and 23.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Interesting, thanks for the link. Even for just released qemu-4.2.0-rc, the documentation does not seem to reflect this at all.